# Does k3s supports the ServiceTopology feature?

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

Does k3s supports the ServiceTopology feature, and if so, how to enable it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it's a feature-gate:
Using CLI:

```
--kube-apiserver-arg feature-gates=ServiceTopology=true,...
```

I have no firsthand experience with running it on k3s.

Comment: Is there a way to verify that it has been properly applied?

I've reinsyalled the ks3 server with `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -s - --kube-apiserver-arg feature-gates=ServiceTopology=true,EndpointSlice=true`

The unit file has been updated, but the feature does not seems to be enabled.

The unit file now contains:
`ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/k3s \
    server \
        '--kube-apiserver-arg' \
        'feature-gates=ServiceTopology=true,EndpointSlice=true' \
`

Comment: given what it does, i'd dig for 2 things: #1. see API Server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57449793/how-do-i-access-api-controller-config-in-lightweight-k3s; #2 Apply a configuration like https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service-topology/#only-node-local-endpoints  to a netcat pod: https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/1982